# Can you query subversion to find all checkins by a specific author out of hours

Tags: svn

I would like to run a query on subversion to find all the checkins performed by a specific user outside of the normal working hours (9am to 5pm) is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have access to the repository files or just client access? If repository, is it FSFS or BDB? (I don't know if that'd make a difference myself, but there may be other options there) If you google "svn log parser" there are plenty of hits, or I was going to suggest `svn log --xml` as a good place to start (but Chris beat me to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken ChrisK's advice, and created an XML file using the following syntax...

```
svn log <url> --xml <path>
```

And then used the following query in LinqPad C# Statements to identify all checkins out of hours....

```
var xml = XElement.Load (@"c:\\work\\log.xml");

var query =
  from logEntry in xml.Elements()
  from myDate in logEntry.Elements()
  //from author in logEntry.Elements() //These lines get a specific author
  //where author.Value == "digiguru"
  //where author.Name == "author"
  where myDate.Name == "date"
  where !(DateTime.Parse(myDate.Value).Hour >= 9 && DateTime.Parse(myDate.Value).Hour <= 17)
  select logEntry;

query.Dump();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the subversion history als xml output from the command line:

```
svn log <url> --xml
```

You can then write a script to parse the output and apply your search criteria...

Comment: Nice idea - I could use LinqPad to query the XML file.

Answer (score 2):

You could lauch this and specify an hour at a time

```
 svn log | sed -n '/ XX:/,/-----$/ p'
```

Replace XX with the hour you want ex. 22.

**Edit:**
To output all the hours you want, you could do a script that launch this command for every hours, and put it in a log file.

```
 #!/bin/sh
 svn log | sed -n '/ 19:/,/-----$/ p' >> svn.log
 svn log | sed -n '/ 20:/,/-----$/ p' >> svn.log
 svn log | sed -n '/ 21:/,/-----$/ p' >> svn.log
 svn log | sed -n '/ 22:/,/-----$/ p' >> svn.log
 ...
```

Comment: Wow - I'll give this a go and let you know